# Increasing max size of Mongo BSON Objects results in Boost library compile error

Tags: mongodb, boost

I need to increase the max size of BSON objects in Mongo.  Since the BSON object size is not directly configurable, I've attempted to do this by changing the constant in the source and recompiling.

The problem is that any attempt to change  const int BSONObjMaxUserSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024; to anything other than 16 [in this file](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r2.6.6/src/mongo/bson/util/builder.h) causes a crash when the boost library goes to compile.

Leaving BSONObjMaxUserSize as 16 compiles perfectly, but changing it to anything else fails.  I've tried numerous options (8,32, even 7 for good measure.)

I'm experiencing this in version 2.6.6 stable.

```
    In file included from src/third_party/boost/boost/type_traits/type_with_alignment.hpp:19:0,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp:17,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/make_shared.hpp:15,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/smart_ptr.hpp:28,
                 from src/mongo/pch.h:50,
                 from src/mongo/db/dur_commitjob.cpp:31:
src/third_party/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:124:85: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'
       sizeof(::boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE< BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_BOOL_CAST( B ) >)>\
                                                                                     ^
src/mongo/db/dur_commitjob.cpp:147:9: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT'
         BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(void*)==4 || UncommittedBytesLimit > BSONObjMaxInternalSize * 6 );
         ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:124:86: error: template argument 1 is invalid
       sizeof(::boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE< BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_BOOL_CAST( B ) >)>\
                                                                                      ^
src/mongo/db/dur_commitjob.cpp:147:9: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT'
         BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(void*)==4 || UncommittedBytesLimit > BSONObjMaxInternalSize * 6 );
         ^
src/mongo/db/dur_commitjob.cpp:147:102: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
         BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(void*)==4 || UncommittedBytesLimit > BSONObjMaxInternalSize * 6 );
                                                                                                      ^
In file included from src/third_party/boost/boost/filesystem/v3/path_traits.hpp:23:0,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp:25,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:31,
                 from src/mongo/util/paths.h:21,
                 from src/mongo/db/storage/durable_mapped_file.h:35,
                 from src/mongo/db/dur.h:34,
                 from src/mongo/db/dur_commitjob.h:34,
                 from src/mongo/db/dur_commitjob.cpp:33:
src/third_party/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214:36: error: 'boost::system::posix_category' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
     static const error_category &  posix_category = generic_category();
                                    ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215:36: error: 'boost::system::errno_ecat' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
     static const error_category &  errno_ecat     = generic_category();
                                    ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216:36: error: 'boost::system::native_ecat' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
     static const error_category &  native_ecat    = system_category();
                                    ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
scons: *** [build/linux2/normal/mongo/db/dur_commitjob.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the maximum BSON size (and what are you trying to change it to)? Generally documents approaching the current 16MB limit also correlate with poorly performing schema design (for example, arrays with unbounded growth). If you need to store large binary data there is a [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) convention which is useful.

Comment: Going from the message, what is `UncommittedBytesLimit` set to? Did you change that by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not been a problem here:

- cloned 0ae940b456ceafc3a0d47 from github
- changed builder.h:

  ```
  diff --git a/src/mongo/bson/util/builder.h b/src/mongo/bson/util/builder.h
  index ae31074..8e34aee 100644
  --- a/src/mongo/bson/util/builder.h
  +++ b/src/mongo/bson/util/builder.h
  @@ -63,7 +63,7 @@ namespace mongo {
          update $push (append) operation
          various db.eval() type operations
      */
  -    const int BSONObjMaxUserSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
  +    const int BSONObjMaxUserSize = 24 * 1024 * 1024;

      /*
          Sometimes we need objects slightly larger - an object in the replication local.oplog
  ```

Compiles cleanly with `scons -j 8`. Here's my system information:

1. OS version

   ```
   /tmp/mongo$ lsb_release -a
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
   Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
   Release:    14.04
   Codename:   trusty
   ```
2. kernel version

   ```
   /tmp/mongo$ uname -a
   Linux desktop 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   ```
3. gcc version

   ```
   /tmp/mongo$ gcc -v
   Using built-in specs.
   COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
   Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
   Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
   Thread model: posix
   gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
   ```
4. boost version

   ```
   /tmp/mongo$ dpkg --status libboost-all-dev 
   Package: libboost-all-dev
   Status: install ok installed
   Priority: optional
   Section: libdevel
   Installed-Size: 26
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
   Architecture: amd64
   Source: boost-defaults
   Version: 1.54.0.1ubuntu1
   ```